# NSFetchedResultsController Mac OSX Cocoa equivalent

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-data

I am porting some Core Data code from iPhone to Mac OS X.

Problem is that the Core Data Framework on Mac OS X does not have `NSFetchedResultsController.h` nor `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` protocol declared; at least I am not able to force a Cocoa application to see this class even if I drag Core Data Framework from the iPhone project to link with the Mac Application.

Anyone faced this problem ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On Mac OS X, you should probably be taking advantage of the Cocoa controllers. [NSArrayController](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSArrayController_Class) is probably what you want.

Comment: Here is an excellent tutorial that illustrates how to use an NSArrayController like Barry suggested. http://www.raywenderlich.com/21752/how-to-use-cocoa-bindings-and-core-data-in-a-mac-app

Comment: Forunately NSFetchedResultsController is now available for Cocoa, because NSArrayController method was first created by satan himself as almost everything Cocoa compared to iOS.

Answer (score 4):

`NSFetchedResultsController` is now available on Mac OS X, 10.12 and above. 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller