# CoreData and big tables

Tags: cocoa, sqlite, core-data

I have a Cocoa Mac application with a search field and a collection view bound to an sqlite table through CoreData. The table contains several hundred thousand records with text fields (name, place, ...) indexed by name. I'm using BEGINSWITH predicate in a search field binding to select a dozen of records for display in a collection view. Everything works fine, but the problem is that CoreData loads the whole table into memory at the first query request and only then does the necessary filtering of records for display which means considerable delay for the user.

Is there a way to set up CoreData so that the whole table does not load into memory? Ideally, I would like to fetch only the first 100 items from a range of alphabetically sorted records for every query in the search field.

Comment: Some advice. You do not have "a collection view bound to an sqlite table through CoreData." Core Data is not SQL. Entities are not tables. Objects are not rows. Attributes are not columns. Relationships are not joins. Core Data is an object graph management system that may or may not persist the object graph and may or may not use SQL far behind the scenes to do so. Trying to think of Core Data in SQL terms will cause you to completely misunderstand Core Data and result in much grief and wasted time.

Comment: What makes you think that "CoreData loads the whole table into memory at the first query..."? Core Data doesn't work like that. Are you just assuming that because the app is slow?

Comment: @TechZen: I get your point. My problem is that my trivial application is slow at startup. I tried to figure out what was going on by putting some debug loggings into an NSArrayController fetchWithRequest method overide and I found out that the whole table indeed gets loaded into the array controller at the first request though I only want to display the first 100 records in my collection view. I am new to Cocoa and I am pretty sure it is just a matter of improper setup. I appreciate any hint that could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

On iOS, this would be achieved using a `NSFetchedResultsController`. The following question describes the Mac equivalent controllers (such as `NSArrayController`): [NSFetchedResultsController Mac OSX Cocoa equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429607/nsfetchedresultscontroller-mac-osx-cocoa-equivalent).

**EDIT**

As per my comment below, a `NSFetchRequest` should be created in conjunction with the array controller. This can then be configured with `fetchLimit` and `fetchOffset` to determine how many fetch results are returned.

Comment: Yes, I have been using NSArrayController. The problem is that it gets populated with a query:

select name from mytable;

which is more than 100k records.

I would like to have it populated with something like:

select name from mytable where name like 'j%' order by name limit 100;

so that the array controller carries only those entries that get actually displayed in my collection view.

Comment: @mschuster: To limit the number of results returned, configure your `NSArrayController` to use an `NSFetchRequest`. You can subclass your `NSArrayController` and override the `fetchWithRequest:merge:error:` method. Your `NSFetchRequest` can be configured with `fetchLimit` and `fetchOffset` to determine how many results should be returned by the fetch.

Comment: +1 an array controller should only fetch and fault in the managed objects actually needed for the immediate display of the tableview. Setting the fetchLimit etc helps even more although in my experience it is seldom needed with an array controller.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the fetch request set to fetch as faults only. That way only the objects whose attributes who are actively accessed will be fully loaded into memory.